Type hinting list of child classes when the original list is of the parent's type in Python
Given a variable with the type hint list[ParentItem], how can one assign another list to it with the type hint list[ChildItem], where ChildItem is derived from ParentItem, without triggering linter type checking errors?
Consider the following contrived, minimal example in which the pyright linter throws the following argument type checking error:

Argument of type list[ChildItem] cannot be assigned to parameter items of type list[ParentItem] in function __init__
list[ChildItem] is incompatible with list[ParentItem] Type parameter _T@list is invariant, but ChildItem is not the same as ParentItem Consider switching from list to Sequence which is covariant

class ParentItem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class ChildItem(ParentItem):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()


class ParentGroup:
    def __init__(self, items: list[ParentItem]) -> None:
        self._items = items

    def add(self, item: ParentItem) -> None:
        self._items.append(item)


class ChildGroup(ParentGroup):
    def __init__(self, child_items: list[ChildItem]) -> None:
        super().__init__(child_items)  # pyright argument type checking error here

Changing the line:
    def __init__(self, child_items: list[ChildItem]) -> None:

to
    def __init__(self, child_items: list[ParentItem]) -> None:

superficially resolves the error, but this doesn't provide the desired type hints when the ChildGroup class is used. The error reappears later anyway when one attempts to create a ChildGroup instance using a list of ChildItem instances, e.g.:
i1 = ChildItem()
i2 = ChildItem()
ilist = [i1, i2]
g_with_child_items = ChildGroup(ilist) # same error as before, but regarding assignment to "child_items" parameter instead of "items" parameter

How can the child_items variable of the ChildGroup class be correctly type annotated as list[ChildItem]?

@InSync the linked question does not cover the situation where one needs to perform the type hinting within a class, not within a method. You'll see if you simply use a type variable without deriving from the typing.Generic base class, additional linting errors would arise. The suggested solution in the linked QA of using a Sequence is also not suitable as the _items variable is required to be mutable for the add function to work: the Sequence type is immutable.

The scope of the TypeVar is really not the point, and additional suggestions also don't make the answer irrelevant to this question. Duplicates don't need to be precisely about the same thing.

@InSync Maybe not precisely, but this problem I encountered is something that took a lot of time to find a solution to because many existing questions on this site, and articles elsewhere, did not precisely solve the issue under the circumstances detailed. The point of opening this question was to provide help for those that find themselves in a similar situation in future.

The solution is to create a user-defined generic type variable (TypeVar) that is bound to the ParentItem class, and then to use this type in the signatures of the ParentGroup class' methods where applicable. This will allow ParentItem and its derived classes to be used without type hinting errors in ParentGroup and its derivatives. Note that ParentGroup has to derive from the typing.Generic base class, and then any generic types that are to be used within this class have to be specified (i.e. ParentItemType as shown below).
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

ParentItemType = TypeVar("ParentItemType", bound="ParentItem")


class ParentItem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class ChildItem(ParentItem):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()


class ParentGroup(Generic[ParentItemType]):
    def __init__(self, items: list[ParentItemType]) -> None:
        self._items = items

    def add(self, item: ParentItemType) -> None:
        self._items.append(item)


class ChildGroup(ParentGroup[ChildItem]):
    def __init__(self, child_items: list[ChildItem]) -> None:
        super().__init__(child_items)

The following now works as desired without linter errors:
i1 = ChildItem()
i2 = ChildItem()
ilist = [i1, i2]
g_with_child_items = ChildGroup(ilist)


If you turned on strict mode, you would see that your example works only because ChildGroup inherits from ParentGroup[Unknown] where Unknown means "implicit Any".

@InSync Type hinting in my example here and in the application's code works how I would expect it to work. Changing to strict mode requires a change from class ChildGroup(ParentGroup):, class ChildGroup(ParentGroup[ChildItem]):, but the solution I gave still works fine. So it doesn't "only" work because of the implicit association with Any.

PyRight does not flag g_with_child_items.add(ParentItem()) as an error, though.

@chepner Fair point, inheriting from ParentGroup[ChildItem] as InSync suggested makes sense. I've updated the answer to include this. I appreciate the concrete example.
